# Javascript module - overriding functions

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have the following pattern for a jQuery based JS plugin:

```
var myplugin = ( function ( $ )
{

    // (...)

    var myfunction = function()
    {
        console.log( "Calling default myfunction" );
    }

    // (...)

    return this;

})( jQuery );
```

I would like to enable third parties to override the functions (not necessarily any and all) within the plugin like so:

```
myplugin.myfunction = function()
{
    console.log( "Calling overridden myfunction" );
}
```

Can this be done without defining anything else in the global scope?

I realise that what I want to do may not be feasible using this design pattern. If this is the case what type of pattern should I be looking for?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as good practices go, you shouldn't encourage modification of your plugin.  Instead, you may allow **modified copies** of your plugin.

```
var myPlugin = (function createModule($){
  var module = {};

  module.extend(stuff, function(changes){
    $.extend(createModule(), changes || {});
  });

  module.something = function(){
     return 1;
  }
  return module;
})(jQuery);
```

Now if we call `myPlugin.something()` we get `1`.

If the user does this:

```
var altPlugin = myPlugin.extend({
   something: function(){
      return 2;
   }
});

altPlugin.something() // => 2
myPlugin.something() // => 1
```

This allows us to non destructively modify the behavior or myPlugin.  If the user decides it wants to just overwrite `myPlugin` that'll still work, this just provides a better alternative.

Comment: This does the trick nicely - thanks!

It does seem to allow the functions in `myplugin` to be overridden too and although I concur re best practices, this lets the plugin users decide whether they do it the "right" way or the "messy" way.

Comment: Yep, give the users choice, because sometimes they have weird and terrible requirements.  Also steer those that have choice towards good choices :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this way

```
 var myplugin = ( function ( $ )
{

    // (...)

    this.myfunction = function()
    {
        console.log( "Calling default myfunction" );
    }


    // (...)

    return this;

})( jQuery );


myplugin.myfunction = function()
{
    console.log( "Calling overridden myfunction" );
}
myplugin.myfunction();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j3NFu/1/)

Comment: I know this looks like it works but in fact if you then call `myfunction` from within the module, it is the default function that is called. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not how you want. You can use `||` operator and then use some `options` to be passed.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function (options) {
        // (...)
        var myfunction = options.overRide || function () {
            console.log("Calling default myfunction");
        }
        // (...)
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Now, you can pass any function like:

```
$('selector').myplugin({
    overRide: function () {
        console.log("Calling overridden function ");
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks perfect for allowing a specific function to be overridden. For my case though I do prefer @FakeRainBrigand's solution as this allows any function/variable to be accessed in the global scope if they are added to the returned object inside the module. Thanks!

Comment: @nckprsn if you listen to me, `$('selector').myPlugin.something()` is bad and there is no one practically implementing it AFAIK. But, `$('selector').myPlugin('something')` is more acceptable and is in practice and the solution which you've accepted is also duplicating itself. Just saying

Comment: Have no fear, `$('selector').myPlugin.something()` doesn't even come into the equation.

Comment: @nckprsn as I said, I was just saying. I thought it was a jQuery plugin